# Deleting keys from dictionary but adding the corresponding values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm trying to remove the repetitive items from `Name` and add its corresponding time to the `Duration` but it's much more challenging than I thought and couldn't find any solution for it on the web.

```
Duration = [
    10800, 
    1800, 
    1800, 
    3600, 
    3600, 
    3600
  ]
  
Name = [
    "Real Estate", 
    "ToDo", 
    "ToDo", 
    "Personal Finance", 
    "Website", 
    "Website"
  ]
```

Ideal results:

```
Duration = [
    10800, 
    3600, 
    3600, 
    7200 
  ]

Name = [
    "Real Estate", 
    "ToDo", 
    "Personal Finance", 
    "Website", 
  ]
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to it but I did:

I tried doing:

```
Data = dict(zip(Name,Duration))

for key, value in list(Data.items()):
      if key == key:
          Data.pop(key) and sum(value, value)
```

but I am getting:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

and I'm not sure if that's even the way to go about adding the values.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
from collections import defaultdict

duration = [
    10800,
    1800,
    1800,
    3600,
    3600,
    3600
]

name = [
    "Real Estate",
    "ToDo",
    "ToDo",
    "Personal Finance",
    "Website",
    "Website"
]

result = defaultdict(int)
for n, d in zip(name, duration):
    result[n] += d

result_name = list(result.keys())
result_duration = list(result.values())

print(result_name, result_duration)
```

I've extracted the lists again because you suggested that's the required result, but perhaps the `result` dictionary is really all you're after.

The reason this works and is quite simple is because the `defaultdict(int)` allows you to start adding to an value in the dictionary, even if it hadn't been defined previously.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know such feature existed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the indices of Name, storing the ones to delete, and then remove them at the end from both lists.

```
ind_to_remove = []
for i in range(1,len(Name)):
    # check if this name has already appeared
    if Name[i] in Name[0:i]:
        ind_to_remove.append(i)
# now remove them in descending order to preserve the correct index
for j in reversed(range(len(ind_to_remove))):
    del Name[ind_to_remove[j]]
    del Duration[ind_to_remove[j]]
```

You could instead remove them as you go, but this way ensures you won't get off on your indices.

Comment: Thanks for you're response! I'm not sure what should be printed here as `ind_to_remove = []
` seems to be empty

Comment: My apologies, I should have had `Name[0:i]` rather than `Name[0:i-1]`, since the range does not include the final entry. It was missing the duplicates because they were adjacent. I will edit the code in my response to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for getting back. I doubt the new code worked either.